# What's the equivalent to a .NET SortedDictionary, in Java?

Tags: java, .net, data-structures, enumeration, sorteddictionary

If .NET has a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) object ... what is this in Java, please? I also need to be able to retrieve an `Enumeration` (of elements), in the Java code .. so I can just iterate over all the keys.

I'm thinking it's a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) ? But I don't think that has an `Enumeration` that is exposed?

Any ideas?

Comment: How to iterate over a TreeMap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318980/how-to-iterate-over-a-treemap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TreeMap` would be the right choice. As for the *Collection* of all the keys (or values), any `Map` exposes `keySet()` and `values()`.

EDIT (to answer your question with code tags). Assuming you have a `Map<String, Object>`:

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
     System.out.println(key); // prints the key
     System.out.println( map.get(key) ); // prints the value
}
```

You can also use `entrySet()` instead of `keySet()` or `values()` in order to iterate through the key->value pairs.

Answer (score 5):

`TreeMap` is probably the closest thing you're going to find.

You can iterate over the keys by calling `TreeMap.keySet();` and iterating over the Set that is returned:

```
// assume a TreeMap<String, String> called treeMap
for(String key : treeMap.keySet())
{
    string value = treeMap[key];
}
```

It would be the equivalent of:

```
// assume a SortedDictionary called sortedDictionary
foreach(var key in sortedDictionary.Keys)
{
    var value = sortedDictionary[key];
}
```

---

You could also try the following:

```
// assume TreeMap<String, String> called treeMap
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : treeMap.entrySet())
{
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Which is the equivalent to the following .NET code:

```
// assume SortedDictionary<string, string> called sortedDictionary
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in sortedDictionary)
{
    var key = kvp.Key;
    var value = kvp.Value;
}
```

Comment: treeMap[key] is a syntax sugar that you won't find in the current version of java. You should stick with treeMap.get(key)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [entrySet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#entrySet%28%29) method of SortedMap (TreeMap).