# How to get element position from Java Map

Tags: java

I have this Java Map:

Can you tell me how I can get the 6-th element of the Map?

```
private static final Map<String, Users> cache = new HashMap<>();
```

is this possible? Or I have to use another Java collection?

Comment: see this                                                                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502542/find-element-position-in-a-java-treemap

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Though a bit late to answer. But the option is to use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html): this map preserves the order according to insertion of elements, as everyone has suggested. However, As a warning, it has a constructor `LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder)` which will create a linked hash map whose order of iteration is the order in which its entries were last `accessed`. Don't use this constructor for this case.

However, if I needed such functionality, i would extend it and implement my necessary function to re-use them in OOP way.

```
class MyLinkedMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V>
{

    public V getValue(int i)
    {

       Map.Entry<K, V>entry = this.getEntry(i);
       if(entry == null) return null;

       return entry.getValue();
    }

    public Map.Entry<K, V> getEntry(int i)
    {
        // check if negetive index provided
        Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>entries = entrySet();
        int j = 0;

        for(Map.Entry<K, V>entry : entries)
            if(j++ == i)return entry;

        return null;

    }

}
```

Now i can instantiate it and can get a entry and value either way i want:

```
MyLinkedMap<String, Integer>map = new MyLinkedMap<>();
map.put("a first", 1);
map.put("a second", 2);
map.put("a third", 3);

System.out.println(map.getValue(2));
System.out.println(map.getEntry(1));
```

**Output:**

```
3
a second=2
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution.

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Just to add if you want to use this as `MyLinkedMap myLinkedMap = new MyLinkedMap(myMap); ` you may want to add the call for the constructor for the super class  inside MyLinkedMap class such as ```public MyLinkedMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
            super(m);
        }```

Answer (score 11):

`HashMap` doesn't grantee the order. If you concern about order you should use `LinkedHashMap`

```
Map<String, Users> orderedMap=new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Now when you put an element it will keep the order what you put.

If you want to get 6th element, now you can do it since you have your elements in order.

```
 orderedMap.values().toArray()[5]// will give you 6th value in the map.
```

Example

```
 Map<String, String> orderedMap=new LinkedHashMap<>();
 orderedMap.put("a","a");
 orderedMap.put("b","b");
 System.out.println(orderedMap.values().toArray()[1]);  // you will get b(value)
 System.out.println(orderedMap.keySet().toArray()[1]);  // you will get b(key)
    }
```

Comment: And can you show me how I can get the 6-th element of the Map?

Comment: @PeterPenzov check out my suggestion.

Comment: @PeterPenzov what do you mean by not working. check my example

Comment: Ok, can I get a value object by key value. In my case the key is string.

Answer (score 7):

A `HashMap` does not maintain the order of the elements inserted in it. You can used a `LinkedHashMap` instead which maintains the order of the elements inserted in it.

Though you need to note that even a `LinkedHashMap` has no such method which would give the element at a particular index. You will have to manually iterate through the entries and extract the element at the 6th iteration.

Answer (score 6):

With guava's [Iterables](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html)

```
Iterables.get(map.entrySet(),6);
```

Answer (score 6):

The `HashMap` has no defined ordering of keys.It's Unordered.

You can use `LinkedHashMap` which will store your keys in order of insertion.You can retrieve them by calling [keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), HashMap is a Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits null values and the null key. (The HashMap class is roughly equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls.) **This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.**

That's why it is not wise to use this kind of Collection.

UPDATE:

Based on @Prateek implementation of LinkedHashMap I would suggest something like:

```
LinkedHashMap<String,User> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,User>();
// or LinkedHashMap<String,User> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); //for java 7+

linkedHashMap.put("1",userObj1);
linkedHashMap.put("2",userObj2);
linkedHashMap.put("3",userObj3);

/* Get by position */
int pos = 1; // Your position
User tmp= (new ArrayList<User>(linkedHashMap.values())).get(pos);
System.out.println(tmp.getName());
```

Comment: How I can get the 6-th element of the Map `private static final Map<String, Users> cache = new LinkedHashMap<>();`?

Answer (score 3):

**[HashMaps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)** do not preserve ordering:

**[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)** which guarantees a predictable iteration order.

**Example**

```
public class Users 
{
 private String Id;

 public String getId()
 {
    return Id;
 }

 public void setId(String id) 
 {
    Id = id;
 }
}


Users user;
LinkedHashMap<String,Users> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Users>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  user = new Users();
  user.setId("value"+i);
  linkedHashMap.put("key"+i,user);
}

/* Get by position */
int pos = 1;
Users value = (new ArrayList<Users>(linkedHashMap.values())).get(pos);
System.out.println(value.getId());
```

Comment: It's not working because I have a Object for second value: `LinkedHashMap<String,Object> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();`

Comment: @PeterPenzov Check edited answer. I think this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Order in `HashMap`. You can obtain the list of may keys using `map.keySet()` but there's no guarantee the key set will be in the order which you add it in. Use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap` It will always return keys in same order (as insertion)

Answer (score 2):

A `HashMap` doesn't have a position. You can iterate through its `KeySet` or `EntrySet`, and pick the nth element, but it's not really the same as a position. A [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) does have a position, since it has a predictable iteration order.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `LinkedHashMap` in order to be able to tell the order of the inserted elements. `HashMap` is not capable of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Correct!!
you will have to use other collection for getting values on index(position).
You can use **ArrayList**

Comment: Like this one? `private static final Map<String, Users> cache = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: No you cann't assign ArrayList instance to Map.
`List cache = new ArrayList<Users>();`
but then you only can iterate through this list and cann't get value by key.

Comment: So what example should be suitable?

Answer (score 1):

If the ordering is to mean anything significant, you could consider using a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Concrete implementation: `TreeMap`

Answer (score 1):

Use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap It will return keys in same order (as insertion) when calling keySet().

For mare detail about LinkedHashMap see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

For example to get the element from specific index

Create a new list from your values and get the value based on index.

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> hMap;
 List<List<String>> l = new ArrayList<List<String>>(hMap.values());
 l.get(6);
```

Comment: Ok, how I can get the 6-th element from this code? `private static final Map<String, Users> cache = new LinkedHashMap<>();`?