# How to sort the count obtained corresponding to different data items in java

Tags: java, sorting

I need a program that reads from multiple files and displays a report based on the date range entered by the user.Data in the files looks like:

```
[C445] ComputerName:FRONTOFFICE UserID:YB Yenae Ball Station 7A  LanId: | (11/23 17:01:55) | Client is disconnected from agent.
[C445] ComputerName:FRONTOFFICE UserID:YB Yenae Ball Station 7C  LanId: | (11/23 17:02:00) | Client is connected to agent.
[C7AE] ComputerName:KCUTSHALL-PC UserID:GO kcutshall Station 9901  LanId: | (11/23 13:33:06 - 11/23 13:33:41)|Client is disconnected from agent.
```

I need output like:

```
Computer Name   No.of disconnects
A                   4
B                   2
C                   1
```

i.e No. of disconnects for a particular computer name in descending order corresponding to the entered date range.
I tried doing it but I'm not able to get a consolidated count for the computers and also m unable to do the sorting.The output I got is:

Computer Name  No. of disconnects

```
A               1
A               1
A               2
B               1
B               2
C               1
C               1
```

Please help me on this. Here is the code I wrote

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


public class ReadZip{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        try {
            Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in);

            Scanner input2=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter start date");
            String userDate1=input1.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter end date");
            String userDate2=input2.nextLine();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd");
            Date d1=df.parse(userDate1);
            Date d2=df.parse(userDate2);

            ZipFile zf=new ZipFile("C:\\Users\\Engineeir\\Desktop\\QoS_logs.zip");
            Enumeration entries=zf.entries();

            BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipEntry ze=(ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();

                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zf.getInputStream(ze)));
                String line; String name;String compnames;int lines=0;
                while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {

                    String[] st=line.split("\\|",-1);

                    if(st.length&gt;1){
                        String dates=st[1];
                        String[] parts=dates.split("-");
                        SimpleDateFormat f=new SimpleDateFormat("(MM/dd");
                        String[] ob=parts[0].split(" ");
                        String finaldate=ob[1];

                        Date d3=f.parse(finaldate);

                        if(d3.after(d1) && d3.before(d2)){
                            compnames=getName(st);
                            if(line.contains("Client is disconnected from agent")==true)
                            {
                                //compnames=getName(st);
                                lines++;
                            }
                        System.out.println(compnames+"\t"+lines);}
                        else{break;}
                        //System.out.println(compnames+"\t"+lines);

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String getName(String[] st)
    {
        String[] name=st[0].split("\\:",-1);
        String[] comp=name[1].split("\\ ",-1);

        return(comp[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing as you go, try accumulating the data in a map (key: computer name, value: number of disconnects).  Then sort on the map keys and print the final totals.

Comment: could you please show me how to sort after accumulating the data in a TreeMap

Comment: If you're using a TreeMap, it's already sorted.  Just iterate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318980

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an object that represents a dataset, create a list of those datasets as well as a `Comparator` and call `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`.

Alternatively put the datasets into a sorted collection like a `TreeMap` and use the number of connections as the key.

Note that if you want to combine the data of multiple files you'd have to get any previously created datasets and merge the data of the new file into them (e.g. get the dataset for `A` which might have a connection count of 1 and add 2 to it, if the current file contains `A -> 2`, etc.).

Comment: Could you please help me with the code here..I'm unable to merge the data of the previous file