# Coding error when importing project to another computer

Tags: java

I have a project that I created working perfectly without any errors when doing it at home. However when I import the project to a computer at school, I'm getting two code errors from two different classes.

**First Error**

**Main Class**

```
bank.getAccounts().forEach((i,b)->System.out.println(b));
```

> Illegal start of type ) expected;
>
> Illegal start of expression ; expected;

**Second Error**

**BankProcess Class**

```
bankAccounts.remove(bankAccount.getAccountId(), bankAccount);
```

> No suitable methods found for remove....

I could this be happening? No such errors appear on home computer.

```
package Coursework1;
import java.util.*;

public class Bank {

  //Creates a new treemap in which Bank Accounts will be stored in.
  private TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > bankAccounts = new TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > ();

  //This method returns all bank accounts in the treemap.
  public TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > getAccounts() {
    return bankAccounts;
  }

  //This method adds a bank account to the treemap.
  public void setAccounts(TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > accounts) {
    this.bankAccounts = accounts;
  }

  //This method return a bank account using the account number.
  public BankAccount getAccount(Integer accountNumber) {
    return bankAccounts.get(accountNumber);
  }

  //This method removes a bank account from the treemap.
  public void removeAccounts(TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > accounts) {
    this.bankAccounts = accounts;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to verify that the versions of Java on both of the machines are the same.

Comment: Check if JDK is in same version on both IDE.

Comment: That's because the target machine has another version of java that doesn't support lambda expressions.

Comment: I suspect school computers are using Java 7 or older. Closures only added in Java 8...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know, forEach statement like yours (lambda expression) is not supported in Java 7 and earlier. So my guess is that school computer doesn't have Java 8 installed.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I'm using JDK 8 at home but JDK 7 at school. Am  I able to change the code so that it works on JDK 7? Does it need a complete makeover?

Comment: You just need to change that 'foreach' statement, because lambda expression is not supported in Java 7. Everything else should work fine. If you don't have another Java 8 specific code included, of course...

Comment: I dont understand what other expression I can use. I have been learning all my coding through Java 8. How do I change the foreach statement?

Comment: Here's an example of using foreach statement in Java 7 and Java 8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-foreach-loop  If you need additional help, let me know.

Comment: Ok. I understand. However I try to implement my coding to it and  I'm getting illegal expression errors. 

for((i,b) : bank.getAccounts) {
System.out.println(b);

Do I need to change the attributes?

Comment: I assume you have some kind of list like: `List<Account> accounts = bank.getAccounts();`, right? What exactly does `b` and `i` represent? I believe you should have nested foreach loop like: `for(...){for(...){System.out.println(b);}}`

Comment: I have imported the bank class where the list is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68219/discussion-between-peterremec-and-inside-football).

Comment: Try something like that: `TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > bankAccounts = bank.getAccounts();

for(Entry<Integer, BankAccount> entry : bankAccounts.entrySet()){
 System.out.println(entry.getValue().getAttribute());
}`

Just replace `getAttribute()` getter with a getter of the attribute you need to print.

Comment: what is Entry suppose to stand for?

Comment: Entry is an object, representing TreeMap entry (a <key>,<value> pair). Here's another example of a TreeMap iteration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318980/how-to-iterate-over-a-treemap

Comment: Ok. Managed to do it. It function how it should do.
reeMap < Integer, BankAccount > bankAccounts = bank.getAccounts(); 
           for(Entry<Integer, BankAccount> entry : bankAccounts.entrySet()){ 
               System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString()); }

Answer (score 0):

you work with sdk8 at home and there is sdk7 at your school. thats why sdk8 expressions are not supported by sdk7.